# ContentObserver's Onchange method is not being called while sending an sms

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentresolver

I have defined the following service with an observer of sent messages. The problem is that when sending a message, onChange() method is not getting called, anyone please tell me why?

thanks

```
public class countService extends Service {

    ContentResolver contentResolver;

    MyContentObserver Observer;

    Uri sms_content = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

    public Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    Observer = new MyContentObserver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(sms_content, true, Observer);
    super.onCreate();

}

private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyContentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d("BOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO", "c");
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(sms_content, null, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        Log.d("THEMESSAGE", type);


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For registering `ContentObserver` for send / received SMS you will need to register ContentObserver for `"content://sms"` instead of `"content://sms/sent"` and put your  logic for getting incoming or outgoing sms inside `onChange` method of `ContentObserver`:

Change your service `onCreate()` as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
Observer = new MyContentObserver();
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
                  Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, Observer);
super.onCreate();

}
```

and in MyContentObserver `ContentObserver` you can check for send/received SMS and make sure you have add SMS READ Permission in Manifast :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: it worked!!! but am having trouble while trying to implement OnChange method, when an SMS is sent,is there any other way?, thanks :)

Comment: Why is it you cannot observe content://sms/sent?